# How to define a TypeVar for Counter[str] with Python 3.5's type hinting

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

## Question 1:

I'd like to define a bag-of-words type alias using Python 3.5's type hinting syntax, something along the lines of:

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import TypeVar

# define bag-of-words type
Bow = TypeVar('Bow', Counter[str])

def process_bag_of_words(bag_of_words: Bow) -> Bow:
    ...
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make Counter accept a type argument for it's keys (in this case `str`; it's values are always `int`s).

### Option 1:

Since counter is a subclass of dict, an alternative might be something like:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Dict

# define bag-of-words type
Bow = TypeVar('Bow', Dict[str, int])
```

Though this doesn't ensure that I'm working with a `Counter` rather than a `Dict`.

### Option 2:

Another option would be to define `Bow` as a simple `Counter` type, like this:

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import TypeVar

# define bag-of-words type
Bow = TypeVar('Bow', Counter)
```

This isn't very satisfying either, though, since it doesn't enforce the key type on Counter.

Is there a *right* way to deal with this situation?  If so, what is it?

## Question 2:

If I were making my own class, how could I have it accept a generic type parameter?  So if I had declared a class `Foo` in a module called `my_module`, how would I make this legal:

```
from typing import TypeVar
from my_module import Foo

FooTypeAlias = TypeVar('FooTypeAlias', Foo[str])
```

Answer (score 2):

**The purpose of a `TypeVar` is** to serve as a placeholder in the declaration of a generic class or a stand-alone generic function.

**What you appear to be looking for in question 1** may be roughly the following:

```
import typing as tg
from collections import Counter

class Bow(Counter, tg.Mapping[str, int]):
    pass
```

And **to make a generic 'bag of arbitrary stuff' (boas)** instead, you'd use:

```
import typing as tg
from collections import Counter

S = tg.TypeVar('S')  # STUFF

class Boas(Counter, tg.Mapping[S, int]):
    pass
```

In both cases, no class body ought to be required:
All functionality will be inherited from `Counter` and
all typing will derive from `tg.Mapping` in the following sense:
If you declare for instance

```
def foo(bag: Bow, what):
    n = bag[what]
    #...
```

**a static type checker** (iff there is a stub file for `Counter`
or type annotations in the `Counter` implementation)
should be able to infer that `n` will be `int` and
*might* conclude or assume that `what` will be `str`.
**A dynamic type checker** (activated by decorating `foo`,
the PyPI `typecheck-decorator` package will soon provide
something suitable)
might look into the actual `bag` object when `foo` is called
and check some or all of the keys to be `str` and the
corresponding values to be `int`.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I currently have, except that I specifically do NOT wish to create a type alias/name for the `Counter[str]` type. Is that also possible?